# Which version of Node should I use?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

In Node download page there are 2 options : LTS & Current. LTS is version 4.6.0 & current is 6.7.0. I went for LTS. But npm also comes bundled with Node. For LTS, bundled npm version is 2.15.9.

Now npm gave me serious trouble.Many times when I am using "npm install" command in an angular2 project it is telling me version should be 3.0.0+.So I did this:

1. npm install npm@latest -g
2. npm update -g

Then the version became 3.10.3 and then "npm install" in my angular 2 project  succeeded. Am I doing the correct thing or should I have gone for uninstalling the LTS Node &  reinstalling "current" version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular official site it is written,

> Our examples require node **v5.x.x** or **higher** and npm **v3.x.x** or **higher**

So make sure you have 5.x.x or higher version installed for NODE and for NPM it is 3.x.x or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Npm version can be 3.x. or higher but node version you should usr 6.x.x to get compality when using angular-cli